# WCF Service enabling or disabling Security by changing configuration

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, security

I have a WCF Service application and I want to enable or disable security only by changing configuration.

I have two `basicHttpBinding` elements created, one with security, and one without security. Based on the binding I apply, I enable or disable the security on the service.

Here is my config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HostedBasicHttpBinding">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="SecuredBasicHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SecuredService.CustomerService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SecuredService.ICustomerService" bindingConfiguration="HostedBasicHttpBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="SecuredServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SecuredService.CustomerClientValidator, SecuredService"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="SecuredService.CrmServiceAuthorizationManager, SecuredService"  principalPermissionMode="Custom">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="SecuredService.AuthorizationPolicy, SecuredService"/>
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="HostedBasicHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Here, when I apply binding `HostedBasicHttpBinding` and behavior `DefaultBehavior`, I expect my service not to have any authentication or authorization enabled. When I apply `SecuredBasicHttpBinding` and `SecuredServiceBehavior`, I instead expect my service to apply all the configured security (authentication and authorization).

The problem now is even when I apply `HostedBasicHttpBinding` and `DefaultBehavior`, authorization seems to kick in and throws an error such as "Access Denied".

Here is the service code with `PrinciplePermission`:

```
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Admin")]
    public void UploadEmployees(CustomerRequest request)
    {

        ProcessEmployees(request.PacketId, request.Employees);         

    }
```

How can I disable even Authorization when I apply configuration binding without security. My requirement is to enable or disable only through configuration, not touching code.

Answer (score 0):

I see an option - check permission [programmatically](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/11/05/96196.aspx) (skip when security is disabled)

To keep your code clean you can move checking code into single method and use it wherever you need. Or even use static IL weaving (compile time AOP) - for example Fody (method decorator weaver)

Comment: I dont want to use programmatic check as it pollutes the service code. i want to keep service code clean and apply security only thru attribute.